# Compositional data analysis - counts and proportions

Tags: r, regression, compositional-data

I have a dataset where I counted monkeys in 10 plots and assesses the proportion of 5 different habitat types covering the plot. The sum of the habitats per plot is always 100.
I would like to test whether the abundance of monkeys is higher in plots containing higher/lower proportion of certain habitat but I’m unsure about what method is more appropriate and what R package I could use to analyze it.

Comment: Can you explain what "sum of the habitats per plot is always 100" means? Maybe just describe the experiment and data a little more clearly overall.